# Chrome extension content script - App is not defined on Ember site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ember.js, google-chrome-extension, twitch

I'm writing a simple Google Chrome extension for [twitch.tv](http://twitch.tv) channels.
The only feature I need is to **send a chat message**, preferably without using the chat textbox and button explicitly.

By looking through the source code of [BetterTTV addon](https://github.com/night/BetterTTV) I found the function responsible for sending chat messages:

`App.__container__.lookup('controller:chat').currentRoom.tmiRoom.sendMessage('test message');`

Now, when I execute this using the console in Chrome DevTools, **it works perfectly fine.**

However, **using it from the extension's content script** throws: `script1.js:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined`

The same situation goes when trying to use `window.Ember` (works in the console, throws *not defined* in content script).

Just in case, here's the whole test code of content script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        main();
    }, 5000);
});

function main() {
    var tmi = App.__container__.lookup('controller:chat').currentRoom;

    tmi.tmiRoom.sendMessage('TEST'); 
}
```

---

Although I have some experience in chrome extensions, I've never had to deal with anything about Ember.js. Also I haven't found any similar problems whatsoever.

Comment: See [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: Your `setTimeout` code executes `main()` immediately, not after the delay. You should use `main` without the `()`. Currently you are telling it to execute the function returned by the immediate execution of `main()`.

Comment: One method I've used to test for page setup time issues is to have the relevant code fired from a button. Doing so for testing allows you to directly control when the code is executed. Obviously, if it is a timing issue, you will then need to determine a programmatic method of waiting for what you need to be available. A simplistic way to do so would be a `setTimeout` loop that repeatedly checks for `App` being defined and continues once it is if it is not, then just set up another timeout. Perhaps better would be to watch for the completion of the request which provides the code/information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error happens because of `content_script` and `WEB page` have some DOM layer, but have different JavaScript contexts, so on you can't access WEB page's javascript objects from `content_script`.

Yoy can do thing you want by that way:

1. Inject to the page `proxy` script, which would work in page's JS context and listening custom events from your `content_script`.
2. Send custom message from `content_script` with your message to page's listener.
3. Run your `App.__container__.lookup('controller:chat').currentRoom.tmiRoom.sendMessage('test message');` in listener from 1 on receive message from `content_script`.

Unfortunelly I don't understand from your question what way you want enter message you want send for the chat, so I'll example how to send fixed message for a few times.

### Step by step

Define `content_script` and make `proxy.js` web accessible in *manifest.js*:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://www.twitch.tv/*"],
    "js": ["runner.js"]
  }
],
"web_accessible_resources":["proxy.js"]
....
```

In `content_script` *runner.js* inject `proxy.js` to the page and send messages to it:

```
...
var inject = document.createElement("script");
inject.src=chrome.extension.getURL("proxy.js");
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(inject);


// replace it with your code which sends message to the proxy, now for example it sends "Hi!" message for every second
setInterval('window.postMessage({"event":"chatMessage","value":"Hi!"},"*");',1000);
...
```

In *proxy.js* listen message and proxy it to the chat if it's your event:

```
...
window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    if(event.data.hasOwnProperty("event") && event.data.event == "chatMessage")
    {
        App.__container__.lookup('controller:chat').currentRoom.tmiRoom.sendMessage(event.data.value);
    }
});
...
```

That's all! :)

### Read more

Chrome content scripts docs about cross-page comminication: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication